# How can I detect window size with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect window/browser size with jQuery like Gmail? In Gmail, we don't need to refresh or reload current page as soon as we have changed window resolution in window setting? In my project, I need to refresh the browser as soon as window setting has been changed.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that we can not. But we can get size of window by use: `document.body.clientWidth/clientHeight`

Comment: Update: I am wrong. You can screen.width and screen.height

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You cannot really find the display resolution from a web page. There *is* a CSS Media Queries statement for it, but it is poorly implemented in most devices and browsers, if at all. However, you do not need to know the resolution of the display, because changing it causes the (pixel) width of the window to change, which *can* be detected using the methods others have described:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // This will execute whenever the window is resized
  $(window).height(); // New height
  $(window).width(); // New width
});
```

You can also use CSS Media Queries in browsers that support them to adapt your page's style to various display widths, but you should really be using `em` units and percentages and `min-width` and `max-width` in your CSS if you want a proper flexible layout. Gmail probably uses a combination of all these.

Comment: thanks resize, but `$(window).resize` not work to android tv! Best use `setInterval` is work fine without time. ;)

Answer (score 17):

You make one div somewhere on the page and put this code:

```
<div id="winSize"></div>
<script>
    var WindowsSize=function(){
        var h=$(window).height(),
            w=$(window).width();
        $("#winSize").html("<p>Width: "+w+"<br>Height: "+h+"</p>");
    };
   $(document).ready(WindowsSize); 
   $(window).resize(WindowsSize); 
</script>
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
var WindowsSize=function(){
     var h=$(window).height(),
      w=$(window).width();
     $("#winSize").html("<p>Width: "+w+"<br>Height:"+h+"</p>");
 };
 $(document).ready(WindowsSize); 
 $(window).resize(WindowsSize);
```

```css
#winSize{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:1%;
  right:1%;
  border:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 3px solid;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  padding:5px 10px;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:#000 1px 1px 1px,#000 -1px 1px 1px;
  z-index:9999
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="winSize"></div>
```

Of course, adapt it to fit your needs! ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can get the values for the width and height of the browser using the following:

```
$(window).height();
$(window).width();
```

To get notified when the browser is resized, use this bind callback:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//get dimensions 
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

//refresh on resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  location.reload(true)
});
```

not sure if you wanted to tinker with the dimensions of elements or actually refresh the page. so here a bunch of different things pick what you want.  you can even put the height and width in the resize event if you really wanted.

Comment: If you refresh on resize, it will refresh the page every time you scroll on a mobile web browser, as the screen gets bigger when the address-bar hides.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to detect when the window has been resized?

You can use JQuery's [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to attach a handler.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use plain Javascript `window.innerWidth` to compare width.

But use jQuery's `.resize()` fired automatically for you:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  // your code...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/resize/