# How to place a div in a way the user always needs to scroll to see it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, position

I want to build a website with a div on top, that is always 100%  in "height" (regardless of the users screen size or size of the browser window), so that every other content on the site, is "hidden" and the user needs to scroll down to watch it.

1. Problem: Every time I use 100% in a div height, and float another div to be beneath the first one, the second div moves to the far bottom of the site. I don't find a way to use height:100% in a good way.
2. Problem: I want to place content in the first div that is center center. Like in this  [example](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html), and combine it with the above described example.

I hope my description is clear enough, any help is welcome.

regards.

Comment: set 100% heights to `<body>` and `<html>` and place you div with bottom:0 and y-offset -..px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery for finding resolution and set in element's width and height:

html:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();

    $('#test').css({width: w, height: h, background: '#bbb', position: 'absolute', top: "0", left: 0});
});
```

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789043/how-can-i-detect-window-size-with-jquery)

Comment: that looks interesting, I was thinking of that possibility. but is there a way to do it with css only?

Comment: CSS can not do this, I write a little script in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chalist/CrUmb/

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'll try that one.. but it will take me some time.

Comment: it works so far!! even with the dead-center stuff in the upper div. next problem now is: how do i place a div beneath the top div? tried it with float, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: add $('#div2').css({background: '#000', position: 'absolute', top: h}); for a second div, that is always under the "scroll belt"

Answer (score 0):

give z-index to div accordingly and apply margin-top property to the div you want to be scrolled

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body{
 height:100%;
 overflow:scroll;
 }
```

in html:

```
 div{position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:-100px; }
```

P.S.
not tested
correct me if I wrong

Answer (score 0):

It works, thanks to chalist!
I managed to place a div (div2) that has a top:{window.height} 
So regardless of screensize/windowssize: you always need to scroll to see div2 
div1 is always 100% in height and width, so perfect place for some "background-position:cover;" magick. 
Great!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

$('#div1').css({width: "100%", height: h, background: '#000', position: 'absolute', top: "0", left: 0});
$('#div2').css({background: '#000', position: 'absolute', top: h});
        });
```