# Making sticky sidebar responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a sticky sidebar but can't make it go to the bottom of the page when a media query is triggered.

It's working really well on desktop, but when resizing the page it will have a fixed position in top of everything.

```
<script>$.lockfixed("#spot_menu",{offset: {top: 0, bottom: 300}});</script>
```

I want it to have a relative position but CSS media query wont work in my media query:

```
#spot_menu { position: relative; }
```

Any idea of how to do this? Thank you

Comment: You're setting your position with JS, so your media query could also be in JS, using something like `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. See http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

Comment: A little hazy on what you are trying to do...but jquery has a `css` method you can use to manipulate css if that helps

Comment: @stephenhay it looks nice but is not supported by IE...

Comment: @ewizard you mean toggling a css class? But how do I know the media query size I want to toggle the class by JS?

Comment: hmmm - ur gonna have to explain `media query` to me briefly

Comment: by `media query size` are you talking about the size of the container the media is in?

Comment: @ewizard  want to say in JS: When the window size is "X" do this, otherwise, don't do it basically.

Comment: Then as @ewizard says, you should look at http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: ah ok - this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789043/how-can-i-detect-window-size-with-jquery

Comment: That might do the trick! I've also found data-interchange from Foundation that could do it also. Thanks guys!

Comment: cool - let me know - i posted an answer if it is right

Answer (score 0):

Something like (where `x` is the value you are checking against):

```
var height = $(window).height();

if(height === x) {
  ...
}
```

You could also use `$(window).width()` depending on what you are measuring.